can "Winston" (npm) print stacktrace when using format.printf?
I want Winston (presently, using 3.15.0) to create a logger with a function error which takes an error message (string) and an Error as its arguments. This function would print the error message as a console log with some formatting (level, timestamp, and not JSON-formatted) and then the full stack trace.
My code:
const winston = require('winston');

const format = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.printf(i => `${i.timestamp} [${i.level}] ${i.message}`)
)
// note: if winston.format.printf([...]) is replaced with winston.format.json(), the full stack is included

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    levels: {error: 1},
    format: format,
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console({level: 'error'})]
});

try {
    throw new Error('la la la');
} catch(e) {
    logger.error('oh no!!!', e);
}

process.exit(0);

What it prints:
2024-11-06T16:30:32.203Z [error] oh no!!! la la la

What I wanted:
2024-11-06T16:31:14.535Z [error] oh no!!!
Error: la la la
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/foo/bar.js:19:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Am I not allowed to combine printf with errors? If not, how can I print formatted logs to the console and still get stacktraces using Winston?

const formatFunc = (x) => {
    let printout = `${x.timestamp} [${x.level}] ${x.message}`;
    if (x.stack) { printout += `\n${x.stack}`; }
    return printout;
}

const format = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.printf(formatFunc)
)

this solution is close enough, the only drawback being that it prints the Error.message twice, hampering my ability to create a custom message, and still print the stacktrace
